# axios Post gives net::ERR_UNEXPECTED_PROXY_AUTH error on request

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt 2.13 with @nuxtjs/axios 5.11.0 . i had no problem until now but suddenly on some PCs and on just one of my POST requests i get `net::ERR_UNEXPECTED_PROXY_AUTH` !!! the code is very simple:

```js
let res = await axios.post('myroute',{mydata: mydata})
if(res.status == 200){
  // do something
}
```

and it works on my laptop both on local server and real server . but on two another laptops with different internet connection, it gives `net::ERR_UNEXPECTED_PROXY_AUTH`